# How do I draw double height text using Graphics.DrawString?

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing, drawstring

I am trying to emulate a POS printer with System.Drawing and one of the functions I need is to draw text at double height. Any idea how I can do this using .Net's Graphics class?

Do I need to draw the text twice as large and condense it or draw normal size and then stretch? Both seem like messy options but is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the transformation matrix on the Graphics object - you can control horizontal and vertical scaling independently.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ScaleTransform and only scale up the y.